# Path from Resources as Content of Button

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I would like to set `Button`'s `Content` to `Path` defined in `Resources`. So I created `UserControl`, defined `Path`, two `Brushes` and button `Style` in resources... and everything was ok.

```xml
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Path x:Key="PageSmallIcon2" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}, Path=Foreground}" Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}, Path=Foreground}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Data="F1 M 19,25L 27,25L 27,33L 19,33L 19,25 Z M 19,36L 27,36L 27,44L 19,44L 19,36 Z M 31,25L 57,25L 57,33L 31,33L 31,25 Z M 19,47L 27,47L 27,55L 19,55L 19,47 Z "/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainColorBrush2" Color="Orange"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WhiteColorBrush2" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
        <Style x:Key="TransparentButtonStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteColorBrush2}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="2" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBrush2}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=SmallPageSizeCommand}" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButtonStyle2}" Content="{StaticResource PageSmallIcon2}"/>
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I decided to put those resources in separate `ResourceDictionaries`. I plan to have more `Paths` and `Brushes`... Also I would like to have only one style for button. Basically I am doing this, because I had style for each of my buttons and `Path` for each specific `Button` was part of that `Button`'s `ControlTemplate`.

So I created three `ResourceDictionaries` `Colors.xaml`, `Icons.xaml` and `Controls.xaml` and then I updated `App.xaml`

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Colors.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Icons.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Controls.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now `Path`'s `Fill` property is not updated when I press that `Button`. Could anybody please explain why it does not work in separate `ResourceDictionaries` and provide me with solution to this problem?

**UPDATE**

So I discovered that problem is in `Path`. When I have that `Path` in `<UserControl.Resources>`, colors in `Colors.xaml` and button style in `Controls.xaml` everything works again.

I also discovered that when I have my `Path` in `Icons.xaml` and I use it in my `UserControl` as button's content

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=SmallPageSizeCommand}" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButtonStyle2}" Content="{StaticResource PageSmallIcon2}"/>
```

and I have multiple instances of my `UserControl`... then `Path` is present only in one instance of a `UserControl` at a time.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. Are you getting any errors in Output Window with debugger attached? As long as you include your Colors.xaml before Controls.xaml, you should get the desired results.

Comment: @NovitchiS No. There is no Error in Output Window.

Comment: The second problem from Update is because you are giving the same Element different parents in XAML. For multiple `Buttons` you are setting the same `Path`, defined as a resource, as `Button`'s `Content`. To solve this you can mark the resource with the `x:Shared="False"` attribute. In this case the XAML Parser will generate a new instance of the Path element for each Reference.

Comment: @NovitchiS Wow... didn't think af that. Luckily it solves first problem too. Please add your answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for:

> I have multiple instances of my UserControl... then Path is present only in one instance of a UserControl at a time

is because you are giving the same Element different parents in XAML. You are setting the content of multiple `Button` controls to a `Path` `Shape` which is defined in resources. For optimization purposes each reference to a Resource will return by default the same Instance of the object and since in WPF each element can have only one parent at a time, only the last `Button` in your XAML declaration will have it's content set to the desired `Path`.
To solve this you can mark the resource with the x:Shared="False" attribute. In this case the XAML Parser will generate a new instance of the Path element for each Reference.

Comment: It seems like this default is backwards.  Why would you resource something if you're not going to actually share it?